# Redis Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

        // Defaults
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

////

```
@Repository
public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepository {

    private static final String KEY = "Student";

    private RedisTemplate<String, Student> redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations hashOps;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        hashOps = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        hashOps.put(KEY, student.getId(), student);
    }

    public void updateStudent(Student student) {
        hashOps.put(KEY, student.getId(), student);
    }

    public Student findStudent(String id) {
        return (Student) hashOps.get(KEY, id);
    }

    public Map<Object, Object> findAllStudents() {
        return hashOps.entries(KEY);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(String id) {
        hashOps.delete(KEY, id);
    }
}
```

///

Above is the code for my redis configuration.

```
@Component
public class dataloader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private StudentRepositoryImpl s;

    @Autowired
    public dataloader(StudentRepositoryImpl s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("hi");

        Student student = new Student("Eng2015001", "John Doe", Student.Gender.MALE, 1);
        s.saveStudent(student);

    }
}
```

I am using the above dataloader to load some data in my redis.

However, i am given the error below.

```
2017-05-16 10:29:06.238  INFO 7432 --- [           main] c.e.R.RedisCacheExampleApplication       : Starting RedisCacheExampleApplication on PCdessy with PID 7432 (C:\Users\desmond\Desktop\SpringBoot\RedisCacheExample\target\classes started by desmond in C:\Users\desmond\Desktop\SpringBoot\RedisCacheExample)
2017-05-16 10:29:06.242  INFO 7432 --- [           main] c.e.R.RedisCacheExampleApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-16 10:29:06.597  INFO 7432 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17f23d9: startup date [Tue May 16 10:29:06 SGT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-16 10:29:07.830  INFO 7432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2017-05-16 10:29:07.861  INFO 7432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2017-05-16 10:29:08.985  INFO 7432 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-16 10:29:08.995  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-16 10:29:08.996  INFO 7432 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-05-16 10:29:09.174  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-16 10:29:09.174  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2579 ms
2017-05-16 10:29:09.405  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.408  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.409  INFO 7432 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-16 10:29:09.451  WARN 7432 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-05-16 10:29:09.453  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-16 10:29:09.467  INFO 7432 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-16 10:29:09.471 ERROR 7432 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am i doing wrong here? My properties file is empty by the way. Please help thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this(Every bean object should be @Autowired instead of just initializing it using "new" operator):

### Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

        // Defaults
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(@Autowired JedisConnectionFactory cf) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(@Autowired RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

### Repository class

```
@Repository
public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepository {

    private static final String KEY = "Student";

    private RedisTemplate<String, Student> redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations hashOps;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        hashOps = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        hashOps.put(KEY, student.getId(), student);
    }

    public void updateStudent(Student student) {
        hashOps.put(KEY, student.getId(), student);
    }

    public Student findStudent(String id) {
        return (Student) hashOps.get(KEY, id);
    }

    public Map<Object, Object> findAllStudents() {
        return hashOps.entries(KEY);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(String id) {
        hashOps.delete(KEY, id);
    }
}
```